# Python NetCDF4 library RAM usage

Tags: python-3.x, memory, netcdf

I have troubles understanding how data storage is handled by Python `netCDF4` library when reading data from a file. It seems like almost nothing is loaded in RAM. Here is a sample of code :

```
import os
from netCDF4 import Dataset

os.popen('free -m').readlines()  # Used memory: 37615 MB

my_ncd = Dataset("my.nc", "r+")

os.popen('free -m').readlines()  # Used memory: 37620 MB
```

The `Dataset` object occupies 5 MB of RAM, which stumps me because the `my.nc` file size is 997 MB. Is a `Dataset` object just an index helping accessing data on the hard drive, or did I missed something obvious in the module documentation?

Comment: The data isn't actually read until you call something like `my_ncd.variables['var'][:]`. Note that even `my_ncd.variables['var']` won't significantly increase memory usage, the data isn't actually read until the `[:]` part.

Comment: Consider what would happen if you open a NetCDF4 file of a size 20GB and it would all be loaded to memory? Also considering that file in disk is compressed and in memory usually not?

Comment: @Bart Actually, `my_ncd.variables['var'][:]` seems not to increase memory use that much, too. Even after an instruction like `tmp = my_ncd.variables['var'][:]`.

Comment: @kakk11 So, did I miss something obvious in the [module doc](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) ? I mean, obviously a 20 GB file won't fit in RAM, but this is not my point...

Comment: But does the increase make sense, e.g. comparing `tmp.size*tmp.dtype.itemsize` with the increase in memory that you see from `free -m`?

Comment: @Bart No, on the test I did, i had `tmp.size*tmp.dtype.itemsize` about equal to 22 MB while memory use grew of 4 MB.

Comment: Strange, in that case I'm lost on what might cause this...

Comment: I think @Bart answer was pretty clear, the data is not read until you access the data. Just opening the file gives you access to the metada, i.e. you can see what variable, dimensions etc are in the file.

Comment: @kakk11 I tried that on my Linux system (actually read the data to memory), and in my case it indeed gave the ~expected increase in memory, but the same test didn't work for Lyudline.

Comment: It's a really quick 'n dirty script I wrote, but this perfectly reproduces what you would expect in terms of memory usage: https://pastebin.com/TBhs0Dcd

Comment: @Bart Thanks for your script. The output is `expected mem = ~76 MB, used = 77 MB`. After checking, I think I messed up something with the size of my variables. I understand now how NetCDF works. Thank you for your efforts ! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run following code with `python -m memory_profiler <script.py> <input_file.nc> <variable_name>` then you can see what actually happens, use your own nc file with reasonable size. The reason why data is not loaded to memory is that this is exactly why file formats like HDF5 (or NetCDF4 that is based on HDF5) habe been developed for: working with large and complex datasets. HDF5 file can contain TB-s of data with thousands of variables.

```
import sys
from netCDF4 import Dataset

@profile
def openthis(infile, invar):
    ff = Dataset(infile)
    abc = ff.variables[invar][:]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    variable_name = sys.argv[2]
    openthis(file_name, variable_name)
```

Comment: Now I understand that variables are loaded on the fly. Thanks for your help ! :-D